# Get Response Headers from Microsoft Graph Client

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I'm using an old version of Microsoft.Graph (v1.15) and I am trying to check the response headers when calling MS Graph Client.
Am I doing this the right way? Or is there a smarter way to fetch the Headers?

```
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, graphClient.Groups.RequestUrl);
var response = await graphClient.HttpProvider.SendAsync(request).ConfigureAwait(false);
Console.WriteLine(response.Headers.ToString());
```

Ideally I don't want to create HttpRequestMessage, and make the API call directly while also getting the response headers, but I was not able to find a way to fetch the headers with the returned variable below.

```
await graphClient.Groups.Request().GetAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

I read in the latest v4 release, there is .GetResponseAsync() which makes retrieving headers easier, but it's not a stable release yet.

Comment: Were you able to get additional data object in the response? See if you can get some details in it.

Comment: Yes, I checked the Group.AdditionalData dictionary, but nothing related to response header were stored. It contained info like creationOptions, isAssignableToRole, resourceBehaviorOptions, resourceProvisioningOptions.

Comment: I used the below when i used Teams Graph API calls. So try/customize as you wish and see if it helps:

message.Content = new StringContent(graphClient.HttpProvider.Serializer.SerializeObject(body));
message.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
var response = graphClient.HttpProvider.SendAsync(message).Result;
Console.Write(response.Headers.Location);

Comment: Also as a best practice don't use the older SDK/libraries, always i would suggest you to test only with latest once - so that even if its a bug, Microsoft can fix that one for you.